# How to compare a value coming from viewmodel with the textbox value in a foreach loop in view page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In my view page, I am iterating through all the categories coming from model and check with the input value and if matches should display that value in a label.

I need some thing like this.

```
<% foreach(var v in Model.Categories)
  {
      if(v.CategoryId== %>

             $("#TextBox1").val()
      <% ) %>
          $("#Label1").val() =  $("#TextBox1").val();

<% } %>
```

Can any one please help me how to do it? I do not know if I can use javascript next to <% foreach(var v in Model.Categories)
      {
          if(v.CategoryId== %> block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code doesn't make sense for me. Since <% %> will execute on the server side and $("#") jquery will be executed on the client side. In your case I assume that your view already knows the textbox value before it response to the client. you can simply put the textbox value in the ViewData[""] and do something like this:

```
<% foreach(var v in Model.Categories) {%>
  <% if(v.CategoryId == View["TextboxValue"].ToString()) {%>
    <label><%=View["TextboxValue"].ToString()%></label>
  <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Besides, If you want to assign for label in jQuery, you should assign by $("#labelname").html("your value");

Any questions, please let me know!!

=======================================================================================
Below is my new answer for the question.
Then all you need is pure client-side script.

Assume I have a select list like this which's generated from Server-side:

```
<select id="mylist">
    <option value="1" selected>a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
</select>
```

And also have a textbox and a label:

```
<input id="tb" value="" type="textbox" />
<label id="lb"></label>
```

What you need to do is:

```
<script type="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#tb").change(function(){
               if($(this).val()==$("#mylist").val())    
                    $("#lb").html($("#mylist").val();
               //you also can do this by getting .text()
               //while val() = [1,2] , text() = [a,b]
         });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: +1 - don't know how the other 'answerers' missied this point. this was the 1st thing that struck me there on looking at it. of course, i should 'deduct' points from the other answers, but it's not my style :)

Comment: Yes, the above code I have written throwing the error. My doubt is there something that I can write like that. As you said, I can't use the ViewData. Because i dont know the value of text box before the view. The user enters the value from text box and lable should display that value when it matches with the category in category list sent in viewmodel

Comment: I modify the answer...hope it helps!!